# Create a csv file

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

I want create a file with two tables.

For example:

I have this:

```
cat 1.log | cut -d: -f 9 | sort | uniq
```

```
teste
teste2
teste3
```

and i have other command:

```
cat 1.log | cut -d: -f 6 | cut -d " " -f2 | sort | uniq
```

return:

```
hello
good
bed
```

and i want create a file like that:

```
teste | hello
teste2 | good
teste3 | bed
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

although you ask for a csv, you are indeed asking for a pipe delimited file

**you can achieve this with the `paste` command:**

```
paste -d '|' file1.txt file2.txt
```

which will give you the follow result:

```
teste|hello
teste2|good
teste3|bed
```

the `-d` in `paste` injects a chosen delimiter

if you need the result to be have the spaces surrounding the delimiter like `|`, then you can add `sed 's/|/ | /g'` to replace all instances of `|` (no surrounding spaces) with  `|`  (with surrounding space on each side)

```
paste -d '|' file1.txt file2.txt | sed 's/|/ | /g'
```

result:

```
teste | hello
teste2 | good
teste3 | bed
```

just in case, if you want a file separated by commas, then all you would have to change is

the `-d '|'` to **`-d ','`**

which would look like this:

```
paste -d ',' file1.txt file2.txt
```